# How to use variable in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following RegExp and it is **working** fine

```
 var reg = new RegExp(/(.{1,4})/g);
```

But now i want to replace 4 with variable called limit then it is **not working**

```
 var reg = new RegExp("/(.{1,"+ limit +"})/g");
```

How could i use variable instead of fixed value in above RegExp?

Comment: `/(.{1,4})/g` is RegExp literal, so you don't even need to call constructor here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `/`. `RegExp` expects a string or a regex. Then it takes a second parameter where you can specify the flags.

```
var reg = new RegExp("(.{1,"+ limit +"})", "g");
```

More here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 4):

Like this (you don't need the `/`):

```
 var reg = new RegExp(".{1,"+ limit +"}", "g");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this,

```
var reg = new RegExp("(.{1,"+ limit +"}", "g");
```

The second parameter is used for options. And the pattern does not take any delimiter.